# Theme my login and update user meta

Tags: updates

I'm french and I use the plugin "Theme my login".
I want to know how I could update user's meta in a basic page.
Thank's for help.

In the template of my page , I have this code :

```
    $user_adresse_key = 'user_adresse';
            $user_adresse = get_user_meta( $user_id, $user_adresse_key, $single );
            ?>
            <form id="form_livraison" action="#formulaire" method='post'>
                <input type='text' name='user_adresse' value="<?php echo $user_adresse;?>" />
                <input type='submit' value='mettre à jour' name='submit_form' />
            </form>
            <?php
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_adresse', $_POST['user_adresse']);
            ?>
```

Comment: firstly check the values by debugging the code..echo $user_adresse; also check for user id..

Comment: I check and it's return values.

Answer (score 1):

This should go near the top of your PHP script on the page to listen for the submitted data.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['user_adresse'])) {
    $userID = get_current_user_id();
    $userADRESSE = $_POST['user_adresse'];
    update_user_meta($userID , 'user_adresse' , $userADRESSE ); #'user_adresse' should be the name of the meta key
} ?>
```

and the form should be something like

```
<?php $user_adresse = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'user_adresse', true ); ?>
<form id="form_livraison" action="#formulaire" method='post'>
<input type='text' name='user_adresse' value="<?php echo $user_adresse;?>" />
            <input type='submit' value='mettre à jour' name='submit_form' />
        </form>
```

I would also recommend adding a nonce to the form for any front end user interactions.

Details can be [found here](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) under the section of **Adding a nonce to a form**

I have not tested this code so check for any misspellings etc!!

## EDIT

```
    <?php
  if ( is_user_logged_in() )
{
 $user_id = get_current_user_id();
 $user_login = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_login', true );
 $user_email = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_email', true );
 $first_name = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', true );
 $last_name = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', true );
 $user_societe = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_societe', true );
 $user_adresse = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_adresse', true );
 $user_code_postal = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_code_postal', true );
 $user_ville = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_ville', true );
 $user_url = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_url', true );

echo $_POST['user_adresse']; // This will only show what is posted previously on the page - if you want to dsiplay the saved address use echo $user_adresse
if (isset($_POST['user_adresse'])) {
    $userADRESSE = $_POST['user_adresse'];
    update_user_meta($user_id , 'user_adresse' , $userADRESSE ); #'user_adresse' should be the name of the meta key
}
 ?>
<form id="form_livraison" action="#formulaire" method='post'>
<h2>Récapitulatif de vos coordonnées</h2>
<br />
<table style="width:320px">
<tr>
<td>Nom</td>
<td><?php echo $last_name; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Prénom</td>
<td><?php echo $first_name; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Adresse</td>
<td>
<?php  if (isset($_POST['user_adresse'])) { ##This means that if you have just updated the post it will show what the post is updated to - otherwise the original meta is displayed.
        echo $_POST['user_adresse']; } else { echo $user_adresse; }?></br><input type='text' name='user_adresse' placeholder="Ajouter/Changez votre adresse" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Code postal</td>
<td><?php echo $user_code_postal; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ville</td>
<td><?php echo $user_ville; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Web Adresse</td>
<td><input type='text' name='url' value="<?php echo $user_url;?>" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type='submit' value='mettre à jour' name='submit_form' />
</form>
```

[image: Happy Code Result!]

Comment: Thank a lot for help me. I test and $_POST['user_adresse'] return anything in my code.

Comment: Sound silly but did you enclose the top section of code in `<?php ?>` tags - also I missed the tags off the top line of the second block too - I have just edited them in now.

Comment: Yes I did that.

Comment: ok, I have run the code and it seems to work for me. Can you post your code into [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and I can try see what is wrong

Comment: I test this code in a another template and it's working perfectly. I will search where is the problem. Again, thank a lot

Comment: Not to worry - I have had a look at it and put some bits in for you - see edit

Comment: The problem is found. The top of my code is a form with radio button. I will take the response and do an if. So my form (that do update meta data) is in an if. In the website, after I send the form for update, the page reload but doesn't show my form...it's show the form with radio button. If I put my form after the form with radio button, It's work perfectly. So maybe I should send data with AJAX...

Comment: I see, you could always just hide and display the form with java - `<span onClick = "javascript:document.getElementById('form_livraison').style.display = 'block';"> Click to edit </span>` that way you reduce server requests, form has to be set to `display:none;` in CSS but will be overridden by inline via java

Comment: Yeah, thx Bysander. The onclick is the good idea. But why a in a span ? It's not better to run the Onclick with the submit button ?

Comment: My understanding was that you would like people to have the option to edit their information, but don't want to display the edit boxes until they want to edit. The onclick means you do not need to have the first `if` argument listening for the request to edit the profile. It also should mean you don't get into problems when trying to update the user meta in the second `if` statement as you are only listening for one response. *"I will take the response and do an if. So my form (that do update meta data) is in an if."*